# How to create a vectorized version of this code in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, time, vectorization

I tried to vectorized my code but hit this roadblock and can't find an answer to it.

I have this array of 0 and 1, that works like a stopwatch. The way I create it is already vectorized. Here is a sample of it:

[array of 0 and 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y12iU.png)

Now, whenever the array is 1, a counter must be started multiplied by a sample rate, to give me the current measured time. And every time the first array is 0, the stopwatch must be reset for the next set of 1s. Here is a result of it.

[array of calculated time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yJVQP.png)

The code is this:

```
timearray = zeros(size(array01));
for ii = 1:size(array01)
    if (array01(ii) == 0)
        timearray(ii) = 0;
    else
        timearray(ii) = 0.005 + timearray (ii-1);
    end
end
```

The issue with this for loop it's painfully slow. For a large array01 it takes many seconds and I'm pretty sure there's a clever way to do it, but I'm too dumb to see it.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you sure this is the speed bottleneck in your full program? Also, please include an example `array01`. And it would probably make more sense to replace `size` by `numel`, in case `array01` is a row vector instead of a column vector

Comment: Here's a vectorized approach. Is it any faster? (I doubt it) `t = sparse(1:numel(array01), cumsum([true; diff(array01(:))>0]).', array01); timearray = .005*full(max(cumsum(t, 1).*t, [], 2));`

Comment: Yes, the bottleneck was there. The speed difference is massive. Thanks for the code!

The example would be like array01 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0]
The problem is that the array size is 500000 elements

Thank you so much!

Comment: I just measured here, my for loop: Elapsed time is 5.977770 seconds.

Your vectorized code: Elapsed time is 0.002858 seconds.

That is a massive difference. I had 4 for loops like that that I couldn't vectorize. And I have to parse around 150 files... it was taking too long.

Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vectorized approach based on sparse matrices:

```
array01 = [0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0].'; % example data
sample_period = 0.005;                                       % example data
t = sparse(1:numel(array01), cumsum([true; diff(array01(:))>0]).', array01);
timearray = sample_period*full(max(cumsum(t, 1).*t, [], 2));
```